# Lattice Diamond - trying to pipeline but tool is fighting me

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to pipeline a 1-bit signal that has to travel pretty far across the chip (an ECP5 FPGA). The software is Lattice Diamond. The Verilog looks like this:

```
regA_pipe1 <= (combinatorial logic);
regA_pipe0 <= regA_pipe1;
regA <= regA_pipe0;
```

However I can't get timing closure because of routing delays. I looked at the physical layout that was produced, and the software has placed regA_pipe0 and regA_pipe1 right next to each other! Which totally negates the point of having more than 1 pipeline register.

Is there a way to prevent this "optimization"? Like a keyword or something?

NOTE - I ran the synthesis tool with a massive number of placement runs (like 30 minutes) and it finally achieved timing closure. But I'm still hoping for an answer on this issue.

Comment: 30 minutes is nothing to complain about depending on the complexity of your design.

Comment: The issue is that it's not a complex design... I just want a way to tell the software "don't put these registers near each other"

Comment: 'Dont put these registers near each other' can be done by 'floor planning' them, but that's only useful if you also floorplan the (combinatorial logic) and regA. By now, you're manually taking over the placement and likely to get a poor job as a result.

Comment: What speed are you trying to run?  How many level of combitational logic are in the failing path?

Comment: I'd love to write an answer but I have none. I also spent a while with this "two pipeline registers end up in the same PFU and don't get distributed along the path". The software is really stubborn on that one.

Comment: "I can't get timing closure" means a constraint is failing. What constraint is failing? Usually there is a clock constraint on each path between registers. Is it a setup or hold failure? What is in that path? If there is no logic in the path, then you are saying "a timing constraint on a straight piece of wire is failing". If that is the case there is something wrong with the constraints.  Are the launch and destination clock domains of the failing path the same clock?

Comment: @Mikef What makes you think there is a wrong constraint? As I experienced it, it's the software failing to solve routing distance issues by placing one of the two pipeline FF in a different place. This happens even if the problematic path is just a 1:1 connection without any fan-out.

Comment: It could be a wrong or missing constraint. The timing analyzer uses the constraints to determine if the delay accumulated on a path is to long. What constraint is failing? Seems to be a lack of understanding about constraints. If this is a timing/constraint failure on a straight piece of wire that can be caused by several things. Then no amount of moving registers will the failure go away. I would pull this post down and re-post the question something like 'FPGA fails timing' path on a 1:1 connection'. This would clarify the issue.

Comment: If the launch and destination clock are different, then you need to set use another constraint to tell the tool to NOT analyze timing between clock domains in order to make the timing analyzer happy. This has other issues that affect the design that can be worse than the timing analyzer being unhappy. This would be a case of a clock-domain crossing which requires special care WRT design and constraints. Avoid clock-domain crossing if possible.

Comment: To answer your questions: there is no combinatorial logic in the pipeline path - it is literally as written in the OP. The pipelining is only to deal with a long routing path. The source has a 320MHz clock (so the max data switching frequency is 160MHz), and the destination is an IO pin. Ideally, the software would space out the pipeline registers evenly along the routing path, but instead it places the pipeline registers in the same PFU, rendering them useless and causing failure in setup time for the IO pin.

There are no complicating issues like clock domains.

Comment: A couple of things.  320 is fast.  That means you have <3.2ns to get out of the part from a register inside the part.   Xilinx FPGAs have special IO blocks which contain registers to get out of the part quickly.  I don't know if the device you are using has such registers.

Comment: Also, there may be a synthesis attribute that you can put on a register to tell the tool to pack the register into an IOB ring flip flop.  Check the synthesis guide I linked to.  If not then you might be stuck with that timing.  You can put a 'timing ignore' or 'false path' constraint on then register.  In order to do this you need to know what is going on outside the FPGA,  Does it care about the timing?  If its an LED it does not.  If its another digital device on a 320MHz clock then it cares and you need to do something else.

Comment: Look at the Lattice strategy option 'use io registers', try to set it to true.  Looks like 
its -use_io_reg true.  Then re-run the build.

Comment: @ColinMarcus Is that one path only in your case, or do you have many similar paths? If not too many, you can help yourself with manual placement of the two FF per path.

Comment: Is it possible that because the tool couldn't find any timing solution, it's just showing you an arbitrary one?

Answer (score 1):

FPGA Synthesis tools provide a number of different optimization strategies that are global to your design. It doesn't know beforehand what might become a critical path and how to fix it once it goes so far in the place and route process. You can try adjusting the predefined strategies, or if you know in advance that certain paths will become critical, you can prioritize them by adding timing constraints to those paths from the start. A good reference is:

https://www.latticesemi.com/en/Blog/2021/06/07/18/52/ImportanceofTimingConstraints

Answer (score 1):

The syn_pipeline attribute is used to inform the tool to that the designer wants to allow for movement of pipelining registers during synthesis.

It is described in the Lattice Synthesis Engine for Diamond User Guide.

The doc is here:
https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/RZ2/Radiant22_1_Migration_Guide_Diamond.ashx?document_id=53200

I drew a green box around a description of what is is, what is does,  and another green box around how to use it.

The doc mentioned that this is for outputs of multipliers and adders.  It may or may not solve it depending on what the combinational logic is.

There is also an option to turn on global pipelining rather than specifying individual registers.  This may help if the other does not.

I would experiment with these and see what works for your design.

[image]

Comment: Colins issue is that the two pipeline registers are too close. There is no combinatoric logic involved at all. So, optimization on adders and multipliers won't help.

Comment: The attribute syn_pipeline or global pipelining can help if there is combinational logic involved in the path that is failing. If there is no combinational logic (or similar, ram, DSP, adder... something that consumes time) on the failing path then the problem  statement should be 'Straight piece of wire fails timing'. If that is the case there are other problems.